# DIY 433MHz antennas from copper wire

Tags: antenna, software-defined-radio

I need to build two minimalistic antennas for RX/TX at ~433MHz. 
I have insulated solid core copper wire, but I need to make it perfectly straight. I was thinking of using the type of sticks you set next to plants to support them while growing but perhaps there is a better, less ugly way. What do you suggest?

Comment: can you please update your question with more information ? what type of copper wire ? multi-strand/single-strand ? what thickness ? as well as the antenna design you like to build ? and any further information you may volunteer .... help us to help you.

Comment: It is single-stranded wire, 1mm thickness. I need two omnis.

Comment: If you're just making an antenna, there's no need for the wires to be *perfectly* straight. Just a normal amount of straightness is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the information you have given in the post and comments, the simplest way to construct a "omni" for 433 MHz, is by using an SO239-chassis-connector, and solder/screw the antenna elements directly onto the connector. Make sure the ground-plane elements are bended down, to ensure a close match to 50Ohm impendance.

The single-strand/1mm wire will do nicely without supports.

Here is an example:

[image]

The dimensions can of each of the wire elements would be 300/433/4 (a quarter wavelength), each element would be the same length.

Start with somewhat longer elements, and "prune" them until you have the lowest SWR for the intended frequency.

If this is not what you are looking for, please update your **post** with more information.

Comment: I do have one question though - another ham told me I'd need at least 1/2 wavelength on both antenna and radials to get resonance. I can do that, with your design ( excellent build btw ), I just need some 2-3mm copper for the radials. Is it worth it in terms of reception?

Comment: @user400344, all elements of the shown antenna are 1/4 wavelength. so if you measure from the tip of the vertical radiator, to the bottom tip of one of the ground-plane elements, you get 1/2 wavelength... :-) ... for a GP antenna like this you do **not** use 1/2 wave elements. The advise you were given was wrong

Comment: So effectively, it is a nice dipole?

Comment: not really, it works differently, a dipole would be a balanced antenna (and therefore should not be fed directly with coax), while this GP antenna is an unbalanced antenna, and can be fed with coax directly.

Comment: Would it be a bad thing (tm) to construct it from galvanized steel to make it more resilient?

Comment: if you have questions in regards to what materials to use for antenna building or how to, or techniques of building, why don't you post a new question. short answer; I would not use steel, as the "velocity factor" and "resistance" is quite differently, which may introduce other design criteria.

Comment: That's an excellent short answer, I expected as much. Thanks.

Comment: Tested this design today with an AntennaRig - works perfectly.

Comment: If your main element is 1/2 wavelength then you don't need radials at all.

Answer (score 2):

To straighten single-conductor copper wire, clamp one end in a vice, grab the other end in a pair of lineman's pliers and turn the pliers so that the wire is wrapped around them a bit. Pull to tighten the wire, then hit the wire-end of the pliers with a hammer (going away from the vice). Easier to do than to describe.

Comment: I can't post an image inline, but mine is like yours in most respects. I was wondering if I can just cut the tiny coil on the FS1000A 433M TX module, and solder my coax core to that spot. Can I?  I am increasing the TX module voltage from 5 to 12, hopefully I can punch through a wall or two then. I am retaining 5V to the data pin, would there be any damage from increasing it when the rest of the module is at 12V?

Comment: Moderators: yes, I could start a new question, but these are follow-up questions, and others who need the same info may benefit from a single thread.

Comment: coils add loss - you will get the best signal with the straight piece described in the OP.